# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') using react-redux slice from an API

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-selector

I am trying to loop over the items i am receiving in my slice but i am getting the error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'), i am new to redux i am just trying to learn the pattern here, the connection between the backend and frontend is fine as i tried it before adding redux.

my homescreen component :

```
function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const Listvessel = useSelector((state) => state.vesselList.value);
  const { error, loading, vessels } = Listvessel;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(vesselList());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      Fleet vessels :
      <div className="fleet-vessels-info">
        {vessels.map((vessel) => (
          <VesselCard vessel={vessel} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

the slice called vessels :

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import {
  VESSEL_LIST_REQUEST,
  VESSEL_LIST_SUCCESS,
  VESSEL_LIST_FAIL,
} from "../constants/vesselConstants";

export const vesselSlice = createSlice({
  name: "vesselList",
  initialState: {
    value: {
      name: "",
      component_count: 0,
      inventory_item_count: 0,
      image: "",
             },
  },
  reducers: {
    vesselList: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  vesselList,
} =
  (keyword = "") =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: VESSEL_LIST_REQUEST });
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/vessels/info"
      );

      dispatch({
        type: VESSEL_LIST_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: VESSEL_LIST_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.detail
            ? error.response.data.detail
            : error.message,
      });
    }
  };
export default vesselSlice.reducer;
```

how the api look

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
         "component_count": 3,
        "inventory_item_count": 1,
        "name": "Aylah",
        "imo": "Aylah123",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/vessel_image/aylah.jpg"
    },]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I can't see where `vessels` is defined, it might be `Listvessel` instead, but still, it might throw an error, because it might not have loaded yet from API. So you might have to check if the variable is null or empty at first. some thing like:

```
if(!Listvessel){
return "Loading..."
}

return (
  <div> //your data or .map function</div>
)
```

Comment: I think i am just making a miss match in my importing and variable naming's it's stating that vesselList() is not a function